# Visual Studio raises an error MT1045 Failed to execute when deploy a MAUI app to a real device

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, maui

I have my `.NET8` `MAUI` application and I try to test it on my physical iPhone. Visual Studio is connected to my iMac and the iPhone to the iMac. The deployment on Simulator is working fine. When I deploy on the iPhone, Visual Sutdio shows this error

> error MT1045: Failed to execute 'devicectl': 'devicectl -j /var/folders/dm/bwmxpbzn6bvdsyy73c_b453w0000gn/T/tmpBkAavG.tmp device install app --device "Enrico???s iPhone" /Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LanguageInUse/1fa03704bb15e35c6f47a701d9d92131e3e0740198296a93338bb3c829bc9cf7/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone15.2-17.3.1/LanguageInUse.app' returned the exit code 1.         0

In the *Output* window, I also notice this error:

> NSLocalizedFailureReason = This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified.
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = Failed to install embedded profile for com.languageinuse.app : 0xe800801f (Attempted to install a Beta profile without the proper entitlement.)

I like to highlight that I deployed the application on the iPhone roughly a month ago without issues. I got the *Provisioning Profile* from the Apple Store and so on.

The configuration on Visual Studio for iOS is the following.

[image]

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: That may because you do not add the UDID of your iphone device in the provisioning file. You may refer to [Add a device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs#add-a-device) and update your provisionig file to contain your new iphone device.

Comment: My device is already configured in the Apple website.

Comment: I have this issue as well.  Perhaps something with the MAUI SR1 released recently.

Comment: @TonyLugg did you fix the problem by any chance?

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, may I ask what is the type of the Provisioning file?  I saw you choose distribution certificate and if you want to install your app to your registered devices, you should use ```Ad-Hoc``` when you create the provisioning profile.

Comment: I tried the `Developer (Automatic)`, `Distribution (Automatic)` and the real `Apple provisioning profile`. I had another idea: clean on the iMac machine the `Library` folder. I'm doing that today.

Comment: I've just created  an Ad-Hoc provisioning file and with it my app can successfully deploy on my iOS device in release mode.

Comment: Because I added the push notifications on the Apple developer website, I downloaded the new profiles and certificates and there is no way to deploy on the real device. I tried to change the `Signing identity` with all options.

Comment: If you use push notification service, you may refer to [Provisioning for application services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs#provisioning-for-application-services).